# Streaming Content from Family Purchase

Tags: itunes, streaming, family-sharing

I have iTunes family sharing with several members of my family.

**Apple TV**: I see the TV shows and movies I've purchased and I can stream them. I can also see the purchases from other members of my family sharing group and stream their movies and TV shows.

**iTunes on the Mac**: Under the *Library* tab, I can see the TV shows and movies I've purchased, and I can stream them without downloading them. Other purchase done by Family Sharing members aren't there.

**TV App on iOS**: Under the *Library* tab, I can see the TV shows and movies I've purchased, and I can stream them without downloading them.
Other purchase done by Family Sharing members aren't there.

What I cannot seem to do on my Mac or my iOS devices is to stream TV shows and movies that family members have purchased. I can go into iTunes, then into the Store, and see all the purchases. I can download, but not stream movies and TV shows purchased by members of my family share group.

So, I have access to the content of family sharing purchases. I can download them. And, I can turn on *Home Sharing* and stream from my iOS device, but only once I downloaded the purchase on my Mac first.

Is there anyway to stream content on the Mac or on iOS devices purchased by family sharing members *without* having to download them first? I can do this on Apple TV, but I can't seem to find out how to do this on a Mac or iOS device.

I am on the most recent OS version for MacOS and iOS.